# Removing a hyphen to the last number of a counter app but also not repeatedly duplicating the same value

Tags: reactjs

### The problem

The counter app that I build can save each number in each entry. And each number is separated using the hyphen(-), but the problem is how can I remove the hyphen in the last number or entry but also not repeatedly duplicate the same number whenever I hit the save button twice.

### What I Try

Although, I managed to get the trick by asking for a solution on chatGPT. But, it turns out it duplicates the same number whenever I clicked the save button.

Here's the code:

```
const save = () => {
    // count !== 0 && setCounter(counter + count + "-"); previous code that adds the hyphen 

    if (count !== 0) {
      const updatedCounter = counter.endsWith('-')
        ? counter + count
        : counter + count + "-";
      setCounter(updatedCounter);
    }
  };
```

I think the duplication of the same value occurs on the else statement of `: counter + count + "-";`
Because I tried to re-arrange the variables and the hyphen by this  `: counter + "-" + count;` and it didn't duplicate the same number twice after clicking the save button. But, the problem is it's not the intended output. Where the intended output would be `1-1-2-3-4` and not `11-2-3-4` or `-1-1-2-3-4`

Also, whenever I clicked the reset button, it returns an error of `Uncaught TypeError: counter.endsWith is not a function`

```
 const reset = () => {
    setCount(0);
    setCounter(0);
    setAddAll([]);
    setAddOnce(false);
  };
```

You can also view the full project in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-m1lykf?file=src/App.jsx)

This is just a simple project with some additional features that I implement to practice my coding skills in React JS. So, comments and suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `reset` function you're setting the `counter` to a **number** instead of a **string**.

Instead use this, this way you'll reset back to your initial value.

```js
setCounter("");
```

Full reset function

```js
const reset = () => {
  setCount(0);
  setCounter("");
  setAddAll([]);
  setAddOnce(false);
};
```